# I need to filter layer by PyQGIS 3

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I have a vector layer that I need to filter and don't to view the other registers. That filter is like the picture, I find a code Python and I executing in console but instruction return other element.

```
python' expression = "\"id_parroqu\"= 1" '
python' QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)'

<qgis._core.QgsFeatureRequest object at 0x000001A24D00DB88>
```

'
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure as your question is not perfectly clear (for me at least) but if you want to filter the layer, use the following

```py
expression = '"id_parroqu"=1'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setSubsetString(expression)
```

If you want to reset the filter, just use

```py
layer.setSubsetString("")
```

If you just want to loop over features of a layer, you should use

```py
expression = '"id_parroqu"= 1'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
# Magic happen in layer.getFeatures(request)
for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
    print(feature)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what i needed